# When to use the word numerals vs numericals?

Tags: numbers

I've always used the word 'numericals' when referring to anything relating to numbers, the same way I use the word 'punctuation' to refer to, well, punctuations such as commas and full stops.

However I recently came across an article that used 'numerals' in lieu of 'numericals'. Which is correct, and what's the difference?

Looking at the two definitions alone, and searching for answers to this question on the internet yields no helpful results.

Comment: You should include the definitions that you've found so that we know what you're having a problem with.

Comment: Yes, Shan ... without dictionary definitions (and hopefully a couple of example sentences from reliable sources), this is in danger of being closed.

Comment: Most dictionaries don't seem to list "numerical" as a noun. If it's not in the dictionary you should think carefully whether you should use it. (And if it's not in the dictionary, that probably qualifies as "can be answered with commonly-available references".)

Comment: @Stuart [second] "it's not"? "is"?

Comment: The only sense of 'numerical/s' [noun] I've found on the internet is the sense 'numerical problems' (ie problems involving calculations: usually in physics, chemistry etc). // Correction; trawling deeper, the 'numeral/s' sense is used on a site named ['Dribbble'](https://dribbble.com/tags/numericals). // And a (conflicting) stipulative definition by [Susan Rothstein](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/abs/semantics-for-counting-and-measuring/numericals-and-how-they-work/28F6AD53E2E591EED789C3372C94F1C7), CUP...

Comment: ('I shall use numerical as a general term for words whose meaning directly involves reference to a particular number. Numericals include, first and foremost, the cardinal numericals such as 'one', 'two' and 'twenty-two' ...'.) Doubtless, ordinal numbers ('second, ...'), number-equivalents (half a dozen, a gross), related terms (brace, sextet ...) will also figure.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I would say [cardinal numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinal_number) rather than cardinal numericals, and I suspect this is the common usage

Comment: @Henry I was showing, and where content not available, guessing, how Rothstein defines the word 'numericals' in her work. I didn't say I'd use for instance 'cardinal numericals' ... and perhaps she doesn't either.

Comment: As a noun, ***numericals*** has [next to no currency](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=numericals%2Cnumerals&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) compared to ***numerals.*** Avoid it.

Answer (score 2):

If you see MMXXIII, you can describe this as the current year written in Roman numerals, equivalent to 2023 in (western Indo-)Arabic numerals.  I have never seen these described as "numericals".

[Google nGrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=numerals%2Cnumericals&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) suggests the overall use of *numericals* is rare compared to the use of *numerals*.  Removing the final *s* would [reverse the pattern](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=numeral%2Cnumerical%2Cnumerals%2Cnumericals&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3), but then you would be getting adjectival use too.

[image]

Comment: Numerical as a noun isn't in Merriam-Webster, Collins, Cambridge, or Wiktionary, although it's not impossible to noun the adjective. But if it was more common it might be in dictionaries.

Comment: A quick glance through Google Books suggests *numericals* might be more common in Asian English than elsewhere.

Comment: @StuartF: It's in the full OED, with most recent citation 2002: *Ever since he established his own..brand.., his watches—with their..curvilinear cases and baroque numericals—have tickled the fancies of celebrities.* But I would *seriously* advise non-native speakers to avoid it.

Comment: Numerical would associate itself with numerology. Numeric could be used as shorthand for numeric X. -ical suffix is often used with -ology nouns.